# Shell script vs C performance

Tags: c, performance, bash, shell

I was wondering how bad would be the impact in the performance of a program migrated to shell script from C.

I have intensive I/O operations.

For example, in C, I have a loop reading from a filesystem file and writing into another one. I'm taking parts of each line without any consistent relation. I'm doing this using pointers. A really simple program.

In the Shell script, to move through a line, I'm using `${var:(char):(num_bytes)}`. After I finish processing each line I just concatenate it to another file.

```
"$out" >> "$filename"
```

The program does something like:

```
while read line; do
    out="$out${line:10:16}.${line:45:2}"
    out="$out${line:106:61}"
    out="$out${line:189:3}"
    out="$out${line:215:15}"
    ...
    echo "$out" >> "outFileName"

done < "$fileName"
```

The problem is, C takes like half a minute to process a 400MB file and the shell script takes 15 minutes.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or not using the right operator in the shell script.

Edit: I cannot  use awk since there is not a pattern to process the line

I tried commenting the "echo $out" >> "$outFileName" but it doesn't gets much better. I think the problem is the ${line:106:61} operation. Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can we see your shell script ?

Comment: are you using ``awk`` in your shell script? reading and writing from/into files with ``awk`` takes hardly a minute.. [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: Shell script should not take that long , it depends on operation though.

Comment: You have to be smart when writing shell scripts. Avoid spawning processes as much as possible. Things like `xargs` are your friend.

Comment: If you handle the file line-by-line in shell script, and it is 30 times slower, that sounds about right. For example, each time you do >>, you open and close the file, while in C you keep it open (you can keep it open on shell script too, btw).

Comment: Shell interpreter is super fast, and IO operation between shell and C should be around the same level. 15 min does not make sense. You probably made mistake somewhere ( as we cannot see your script)

Comment: Please post your shell script and information about the shell that you are running it on.

Comment: I marked this as "bash" since `${var:(char):(num_bytes)}` is a bash-ism.

Comment: Can we see the relevant part of the C program?

Comment: texasbruce, can you tell me how to keep a file open?

Comment: "I cannot use awk" -- actually, AWK is really good at this kind of stuff, but it's okay if you don't want to learn AWK.

Comment: That was not my intention, I thought AWK was about patterns and regular expression. I'll check it out then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As donitor and  Dietrich sugested, I did a little research about the AWK language and, again, as they said, it was a total success. here is a little example of the AWK program:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
    option=substr($0, 5, 9);

    if (option=="SOMETHING"){
        type=substr($0, 80, 1)
        if (type=="A"){
            type="01";
        }else if (type=="B"){
            type="02";
        }else if (type=="C"){
            type="03";
        }

        print substr($0, 7, 3) substr($0, 49, 8) substr($0, 86, 8) type\
        substr($0, 568, 30) >> ARGV[2]

    }
}
```

And it works like a charm. It takes barely 1 minute to process a 500mb file

Answer (score 4):

I suspect, based on your description, that you're spawning off new processes in your shell script. If that's the case, then that's where your time is going. It takes a lot of OS resource to [fork/exec](http://www.bottomupcs.com/fork_and_exec.html) a new process.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the C program? Is it broken? Too hard to maintain? Too inflexible? You are more of a Shell than a C expert?

**If it ain't broke, don't fix it.**

A look at Perl might be an option, too. Easier than C to modify and still speedy I/O; and it's much harder to create useless forks in Perl than in the shell.

If you told us exactly what the C program does, maybe there's a simple and faster-than-light solution with sed, grep, awk or other gizmos in the Unix tool box. In other words, tell us *what you actually want to achieve*, don't ask us to solve some random problem you ran into while pursuing what you think is a step towards your actual goal.

Alright, one problem with your shell script is the repeated `open` in `echo "$out" >> "outFileName"`. Use this instead:

```
while read line; do
    echo "${line:10:16}.${line:45:2}${line:106:61}${line:189:3}${line:215:15}..." 
done < "$fileName" > "$outFileName"
```

As an alternative, simply use the `cut` utility (but note that it doesn't insert the dot after the first part):

```
cut -c 10-26,45-46,106-166 "$fileName" > "$outFileName"
```

You get the idea?

Comment: It ain't broken but it is hard to find C experts to maintain or expand the process.

Comment: I get it but it takes the same time, maybe 1 minute less. I tried commenting tue "echo "$out" >> "$outFileName" but it doesn't gets much better. I think the problem is the ${line:106:61} operation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try the `cut` solution? How long does that take? The result of cut can be modified with a following sed to insert the dot, if you can't live without it.